Why do fully-functional map, filter, and fold-right/fold-left need environment model?
This is one follow-up question of this QA. The comments there focus on how to implement map etc in C++ but doesn't say much about "relationship between environment model" and map etc.
SICP implements map, filter, fold-left (IMHO they are all based on recursion or iteration):
(define (map proc items)
  (if (null? items)
      nil
      (cons (proc (car items))
            (map proc (cdr items)))))

(define (filter predicate sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        ((predicate (car sequence))
         (cons (car sequence)
               (filter predicate (cdr sequence))))
        (else (filter predicate (cdr sequence)))))

(define (fold-left op initial sequence)
  (define (iter result rest)
    (if (null? rest)
        result
        (iter (op result (car rest))
              (cdr rest))))
  (iter initial sequence))

In C++, proc etc can be passed with function pointer.
In scheme the recursive calls of lambda needs to create new env to store local bindings. But in C++ this can be done in stack. For iter definition in fold-left, we can use struct and then define local func iter there (operator() make local bindings possible). Can I understand that "environment model" is just needed to ensure lambda call to function right, but that can be also done by stack?

Note the "as convenient as Scheme". With C++, you need to explicitly capture things, and think about whether to capture by reference or value, and if capturing by reference you need to take great care about object lifetimes.

@molbdnilo Thanks very much. "object lifetimes" implies passing func pointer may fail at some time. This is why environment model is useful since if we pass one lambda object explicitly like (map (lambda (x) x) items), then proc will just be binded to (lambda (x) x) in the new env created when procedure application. This won't be influenced by garbage collector in Scheme or destructor in C++. I understand this problem now.

Questions about processing models seem more appropriate for [cs.se], I think.

this is mostly about closures. specifically, this can't be done on stack in general, especially when the closure/function modifies the captured bindings. I've posted an answer to your previous question.
